# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.Deferred"

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, coroutine

I am facing this issue when using coroutine with retrofit, can you please let me know why i am getting this error

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.Deferred" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.coroutines.retrofit.kotlin-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]**

while i am using the below dependencies,

implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-experimental-adapter:1.0.0'

implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.1'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'

and the kotlin version is :
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'

Comment: Why you are using experimental version?

Comment: I tried with ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0' but still i got same error for Deferred,

The api service is :

@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@GET(ApiClient.POSTS_URL)
fun getPosts(): Deferred<Response<List<Posts>>>

Answer (score 14):

> Add this dependency in your build.gradle : (remove experimental dependency for coroutine)

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2'
}
```

> And add CoroutineCallAdapterFactory() for retrofit

```
addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
```

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem, it is the Jake Warton's library problem. It is using experimental references internally.

Using `implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-experimental-adapter:1.0.0'`

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlinx/coroutines/experimental/Deferred;
    at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.kotlin.coroutines.experimental.CoroutineCallAdapterFactory.get
```

This library is **deprecated** . Here is the solution from the library's page on git

> This library is deprecated. Please migrate to Retrofit 2.6.0 or newer and its built-in suspend support

Comment: But then we do not add the addCallAdapterFactory anymore?

Comment: I believe there is no need for that, retrofit calls will just have suspend modifier and you can  launch them normally. Not sure why people would still want to add another library and adapter factory to your project if it works out of the box :)

Comment: nothing more upgrade to latest retrofit and bang .... problem resolve ... thanks alot dude

Answer (score 1):

it works: (pay attention to jar task)

```
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

application {
    mainClass.set("org.example.MainKt")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core-jvm:1.6.7")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio-jvm:1.6.7")
}

tasks {
    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes["Main-Class"] = application.mainClass
        }

        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

        configurations.compileClasspath.get().forEach {
            from(if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it))
        }
    }

    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-opt-in=kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi"
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}
```